# Connectedness of symmetric subgroup of simply connected Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces, covering-spaces, path-connected

Let $G$ be a connected real simple Lie group, and $\tau$ be an involutive automorphism of $G$. Then $\tau$ defines a symmetric subgroup $G^\tau$ of $G$. In general, $G^\tau$ is not necessarily connected. (**RIGHT?**)

Consider the symmetric space $M=G/G^\tau$. If $M$ is simply connected, then by the short exact sequence $0=\Pi_1(M)\rightarrow\Pi_0(G^\tau)\rightarrow\Pi_0(G)\rightarrow\Pi_0(M)=0$, $G^\tau$ is connected because $G$ is supposed to be connected. (**RIGHT?**) Else suppose that $M$ is not simply connected. Denote by $\widetilde{M}$ the universal covering of $M$, which is again a symmetric space (**RIGHT?**), and then $\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{G}/\widetilde{G}^\widetilde{\tau}$ for the universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ of $G$.

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$, and denote by $\mathrm{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ the group of inner automorphims of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then $\mathrm{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ is simply connected (**RIGHT?**) and hence is the universal cover of $G$; namely, $\mathrm{Int}(\mathfrak{g})\cong\widetilde{G}$.

I shall be grateful if any expert helps me to confirm that all the four points marked with (**RIGHT?**) are correct or not.

**QUESTION**

Let $G=\mathrm{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ for some real simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, which is simply connected. Let $\tau\in G$ be an element of order 2, i.e., an involutive inner automorphism of $\mathfrak{g}$. Write $G^\tau=\{g\in G\mid \tau^{-1}g\tau=g\}$. Then, is $G^\tau$ always connected?

Comment: What do you mean by ${\rm Int}\frak g$? A real algebraic group, a real Lie group, and if yes, then which real Lie group?

Comment: If $G={\rm SL}(2,\Bbb R)$, then (the identity component of)  ${\rm Int}\frak g$ is $G/\{\pm1\}$, which is clearly **not** simply connected.

Comment: If $G$ is a connected Lie group that is topologically simply connected (e.g., the underlying real Lie group of $H(\mathbf{C})$ for a connected semisimple algebraic group $H$ over $\mathbf{C}$ whose root datum is simply connected, such as ${\rm{Sp}}_{2g}$ or ${\rm{SL}}_n$) and $\tau$ is an order-2 automorphism of $G$ then the closed subgroup $G^{\tau}$ of $\tau$-fixed points is connected.  This was proved by E. Cartan using Riemannian geometry via reducing to the compact case whose main content is Theorem 8.2 in Ch. VII of Helgason's *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces*.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Yes, you are right. Thank you. I was confused with the definition before. The definition for $\mathrm{Int}\mathfrak{g}$ is the analytic subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}\mathfrak{g}$ with the Lie algebra $\mathrm{ad}\mathfrak{g}$, and hence it is the identity component of $\mathrm{Ad}G$.

Comment: @nfdc23 Thank you for your comments. I checked the theorem, and it holds for compact Lie groups, but I think that it holds for all simple Lie groups, right? However, if $G$ is a connected simlple Lie group which is not simply connected, is there any example to show that its symmetric subgroup may not necessarily connected?

Comment: It holds for *simply connected* Lie groups (both compact and non-compact).  It fails in many cases when $G$ isn't simply connected (but simple in the sense of connected semisimple Lie groups).  For instance, consider $G=H(\mathbf{C})$ (as a connected real Lie group with semisimple Lie algebra) for a connected semisimple $\mathbf{R}$-group $H$ with absolutely simple Lie algebra and $\tau$ complex conjugation. In such cases, $G^{\tau}=H(\mathbf{R})$ is often disconnected when $H$ isn't simply connected in the sense of semisimple algebraic groups (e.g., $H={\rm{PGL}}_{2m}, {\rm{SO}}_{n,n}$, ...)

Comment: @nfdc23 Oh, yes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Although @MikhailBorovoi has given an example to indicate that, regardless of passing to the identity component, $\mathrm{Int} \mathfrak g$ need not be simply connected.  In fact, not only can this fail, it almost never happens:  only for types $\mathsf E_8$, $\mathsf F_4$, and $\mathsf G_2$.  Your question imposes simple connectedness as a hypothesis; do you really mean to ask only about these exceptional types?  It may be that you want to replace $G$ in the first place by $\tilde G$, in which case, as @‍nfdc23 points out, the answer is 'yes' (even if $\tau$ comes from the full aut. gp.).